# Error:Execution failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android

After updating and restart `Android Studio`, I'm getting below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/venkat/AndroidStudioProjects/Ensis Client Projects/SAFAB-SerbaAntikV2/app/libs/commons-io-2.4.jar (No such file or directory)
```

I already tried to clean and rebuild my project but every time I am getting above error.

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.navercorp.volleyextensions:volley-views:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.navercorp.volleyextensions:volley-requests:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.navercorp.volleyextensions:volley-caches:2.0.1'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.8.6'
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

Comment: check the directory for `commons-io-2.4.jar'`. Make sure by carefully comparing the directory path and file name that it is indeed in the directory mentioned in `compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')`.

Comment: make sure you have clicked `"Add as library"`

Comment: Your project isn't able to find this `commons-io-2.4.jar` make sure it is remains in directory.

Comment: Why do you want to add commons-io as jar file. Just specify it like the other libraries and let gradle download it for you `compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'`